# True or false: For all integers $a$ and $b$, if $a$ divides $b$, then $a+a$ divides $b+b$.

Tags: number-theory

I have a given problem and attempted to solve it. I would like to know if I'm solving it right or not.

For all integers $a$ and $b$, if $a$ divides $b$, then $a+a$ divides $b+b$. True or false

What i think is that if you let a=5 and b=20, then it is true because 5+5 divides 20+20, 10 divides 40 which is 4. however if you let a=5 and b=17, then it is false bc 10 cannot divide 34. well it can, 1.5 but i don't know 1.5 can be included...

any help would be great

Thank you

Comment: If $a|b$ then for some integers $k$, $b=ak$. Then...

Comment: then............?

Comment: You must not take a=5 and b=17 since 5 does not divide 17. Think about Babaks comment.

Comment: so can this be true and false at the same? depending on numbers i choose?

Comment: No, it is true, because the initial condition requires that $a$ divides $b$. Since $5$ does not divide $17$, you can't say that $10$ divides $34$.

Comment: thank you very much. i understood now

Answer (score 3):

> however if you let a=5 and b=17, then it is false bc 10 cannot divide 34. well it can, 1.5 but i don't know 1.5 can be included...

Yes, but this doesn't satisfy the condition $a | b$, which is why $a+a$ does not divide $b + b$.

The reason $a + a | b + b$ when $a|b$ is because it's equivalent to asserting that $2a | 2b$. If we know that $a | b$, we can say that $ka | kb$ for $(k \ne 0)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have taken values for a and b as $5$ and $17$ respectively.

In that case you are violating the main condition that a|b because **$5$ does not divide $17$**.
Since the assumption is itself false, there is no need to worry about the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

$a \mid b$ is precisely the statement $ak=b$ for $k$ an integer. So if $a \mid b$, $ak=b$, so $2ak=2b$, so $2a \mid 2b$.